# ArcObjects - Select record from table

Tags: arcobjects, vba

I´ve a project in VBA but I hit a wall that I can't pass.
What I want to do:

I´ve a table (of parcels) with the fields: ID, Name, Area, Scale. For each Parcel there is a different scale!

I input, in a text box, the name of a parcel. I want to "get" the corresponding scale.

Does anybody know how I can do that?

Comment: Do you want a QueryFilter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
Dim pFeatureClass As IFeatureClass
Dim pFeatLayer As IFeatureLayer
Dim pFields As IFields
Dim ii As Integer

Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
Set pFeatLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
Set pFeatureClass = pFeatLayer.FeatureClass

' Part 2: Prepare a feature cursor.
Dim pQFilter As IQueryFilter
Dim pFeatCursor As IFeatureCursor
Dim pFeature As IFeature

' Prepare a query filter.
Set pQFilter = New QueryFilter
pQFilter.SubFields = "PARCEL_NAME, SCALE" 'Retrieve only these fields
pQFilter.WhereClause = "PARCEL_NAME='" & txtParcelName.Text & "'" ''' Text box on form

' Create a feature cursor for updating.
Set pFeatCursor = pFeatureClass.Search(pQFilter, true)

' Part 3: Get the Scale value
Do

pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature

If pFeature IsNot Nothing Then

MsgBox("Scale: " & pFeature.Value(pFeatureCursor.FindField("SCALE")))

End If

While !(pFeature = Nothing)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code example of a QueryFilter.  You could assign a variable to hold your text box value for this line **"APP_TYP = 'PA'"** and update this line **indexClass = pUpdateFeatures.FindField("Dir")** to point to your scale field.  The result will give you a message box of the scale value.

```
' Par 1: Define the feature class.
    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    Dim pFeatureClass As IFeatureClass
    Dim pFeatLayer As IFeatureLayer
    'Dim pFeatureClass As IFeatureClass
    Dim pFields As IFields
    Dim ii As Integer
    Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
    Set pFeatLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
    Set pFeatureClass = pFeatLayer.FeatureClass

    ' Part 2: Prepare a feature cursor.
    Dim pQFilter As IQueryFilter
    Dim pUpdateFeatures As IFeatureCursor
    ' Prepare a query filter.
    Set pQFilter = New QueryFilter
    pQFilter.WhereClause = "APP_TYP = 'PA'"
    ' Create a feature cursor for updating.
    Set pUpdateFeatures = pFeatureClass.Update(pQFilter, False)

    ' Part 3: Calcuate the Class value.
    Dim indexClass As String
    Dim pFeature As IFeature
    indexClass = pUpdateFeatures.FindField("Dir")
    Set pFeature = pUpdateFeatures.NextFeature

        MsgBox ("Scale value = " & pFeature.value(indexClass))
```

Comment: I dont see any need of an update cursor...isnt simple Search cursor enough for the job?

Answer (score 0):

Create a select cursor. I'm not sure about VBA but for python: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000039000000.htm

```
#iName is input testing Name

parcels = arcpy.SearchCursor(fParcels)

for parcel in parcels:
    if parcel.Name == iName:
        scale = parcel.scale
```